# elasticsearch c# nest advanced search

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I have a problem about querying a complex data type with c# nest api in elasticsearch. My model in elasticsearch is like this:

```
"hits": [
  {
    "_index": "post",
    "_type": "postmodel",
    "_source": {
      "projectId": "2",
      "language": "en",
      "postDate": "2017-06-11T08:39:32Z",
      "profiles": [
        {
          "label": "Emotional",
          "confidence": 1
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "_index": "post",
    "_type": "postmodel",
    "_source": {
      "projectId": "3",
      "language": "en",
      "postDate": "2017-06-11T08:05:01Z",
      "profiles": [
        {
          "label": "Fact oriented",
          "confidence": 0.69
        },
        {
          "label": "Rational",
          "confidence": 1
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  ...
```

By using c# Nest API, i want to fetch the postmodels which is projectId=3 and with "Rational" profile. My current code looks like this:

```
var postModels = await _elasticClient.SearchAsync<PostModel>(s => s
            .Index("post")
            .Query(q =>
            {
                QueryContainer query = new QueryContainer();

                query = query && q.Match(m => m.Field(f => f.ProjectId)
                .Query("3"));

                return query;
            }));
```

But i dont know how to query "Profiles". i want to extend my query to fetch specific profiles as well. I would be happy if someone can help me with this problem. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is `profiles` field mapped as a nested field?

Comment: @Rob no, it is not mapped as nested field.

Comment: `m.Field(f => f.Profiles.First().Label)` should be working, also I hope you understand differences between using `object` and `nested` types as they can [hit you in the face very hard](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html) 

Comment: Thank you @Rob i have set the field type as nested and solved the query.